# Monitoring DOM changes in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

Is there a way to detect when the disabled attribute of an input changes in jQuery.  I want to toggle the style based on the value.

I can copy/paste the same enable/disable code for each change event (as I did below) but I was looking for a more generic approach.

Can I create a custom event that will monitor the disabled attribute of specified inputs?

Example:

```
 <style type="text/css">.disabled{ background-color:#dcdcdc; }</style>


<fieldset>
    <legend>Option 1</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="Group1" id="Radio1" value="Yes" />Yes
    <input type="radio" name="Group1" id="Radio2" value="No" checked="checked" />No
    <div id="Group1Fields" style="margin-left: 20px;">
        Percentage 1:
        <input type="text" id="Percentage1" disabled="disabled" /><br />
        Percentage 2:
        <input type="text" id="Percentage2" disabled="disabled" /><br />
    </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Option 2</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="Group2" id="Radio3" value="Yes" checked="checked" />Yes
    <input type="radio" name="Group2" id="Radio4" value="No" />No
    <div id="Group2Fields" style="margin-left: 20px;">
        Percentage 1:
        <input type="text" id="Text1" /><br />
        Percentage 2:
        <input type="text" id="Text2" /><br />
    </div>
</fieldset>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //apply disabled style to all disabled controls
        $("input:disabled").addClass("disabled");

        $("input[name='Group1']").change(function () {
            var disabled = ($(this).val() == "No") ? "disabled" : "";
            $("#Group1Fields input").attr("disabled", disabled);

            //apply disabled style to all disabled controls
            $("input:disabled").addClass("disabled");

            //remove disabled style to all enabled controls
            $("input:not(:disabled)").removeClass("disabled");

        });
        $("input[name='Group2']").change(function () {
            var disabled = ($(this).val() == "No") ? "disabled" : "";
            $("#Group2Fields input").attr("disabled", disabled);

            //apply disabled style to all disabled controls
            $("input:disabled").addClass("disabled");

            //remove disabled style to all enabled controls
            $("input:not(:disabled)").removeClass("disabled");
        });           

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After further researching this issue, I stumbled upon a blog post by Rick Strahl in which we demonstrates a jQuery plug-in that allows for monitoring of CSS properties: [jQuery CSS Property Monitoring Plug-in updated](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/478985.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Although there are more efficient ways of tackling this problem, one way of handling this is by running a function every xx seconds that will set the required CSS classes on disabled elements:

```
window.setInterval(1000,function() {
    $("input:disabled").addClass("disabled");
    $("input:enabled").removeClass("disabled");
});
```

This will check all input elements every second. But again, this is a VERY bad solution. You would be better off restructuring your code.

Without changing too much of your code and HTML, I would do something like this (didn't test it though):

```
$("input[name^=Group]").change(function () {
        var disabled = ($(this).val() == "No") ? "disabled" : "";
        var groupName = $(this).attr("name");

        $("#" + groupName + "Fields input")
             .attr("disabled", disabled)
             .addClass("disabled");

        //remove disabled style to all enabled controls
        $("input:enabled)").removeClass("disabled");
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I suppose your solution does work but it definitely seems like a hack. Hopefully, there is a better way!

Comment: -1 This is not a good idea. For one it's bad for performance, and two, there will always be some sort of lag with this.

Comment: Isn't this what I'm saying? Quote: "this is a VERY bad solution"

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to enable the text inputs in the same fieldset, eh? Give this a try:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
  if (this.value == "No") {
    $('input[type="text"]', $(this).parents('fieldset')).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else {
    $('input[type="text"]', $(this).parents('fieldset')).attr('disabled', '');
  }
});
```

Comment: Please re-read the question.  I am looking to detect when the disabled attribute changes for any input on the page.  I will have a significant number of inputs on the page and don't want to repeat the same logic in each change event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of your layout and make all of your handlers find things relatively, shortening all your current code this:

```
$(function() {
    $("input:disabled").addClass("disabled");

    $(":radio").change(function() {
        var disabled = this.checked && this.value == "No";
        $(this).siblings("div").find("input")
            .attr('disabled', disabled)
            .toggleClass('disabled', disabled);
    });
});
```

[You can view a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/E3gk4/), also since you know which class, elements and whether you want it on or off, you can use [`.toggleClass(class, bool)`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to shorten things up a but further.  If you want this to be more precise, you can give those radio buttons a class, for example:

```
<input type="radio" name="Group1" id="Radio1" value="Yes" class="toggler" />
```

Then you can do `$(".toggler")` instead of `$(":radio")`, same for the `div`, you could give it a class and do `.siblings(".fields")` instead of `.siblings("div")`...the point is if your layout is consistent, use that to your advantage when [DRY coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

Comment: Thanks for answering Nick.  I am no so concerned with the DRYness of the code.  This was only an example, and I don't think my layout would be flexible enough where this would work in all situations.  I was hoping to use an eventing strategy to solve the problem.