# How do I add "disabled" class to the div "A" if div "B" has an "active" class with jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

Lets say I have two divs: "A" and "B". I want to add "disabled" class to the div "A" as long as the div "B" has an "active" class.

How should I do this with jquery? I tried "hasClass" method but it didn't work.

Comment: Please also show what you tried if you want a better explanation as to why it didn't work and how you can improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want div "A" to always have a class disabled when div "B" has class active, add a listener. That way, when you add class active dynamically, div "A" is updated too.

```
$('#parent-of-a').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(e) {
    if ($('.b').hasClass('active')){$('.a').addClass('disabled')}
});
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17881562/3460076

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($('.b').hasClass('active')){$('.a').addClass('disabled')}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $( ".b" ).is( ". active" ) ) {
   $( ".a" ).addClass('disabled');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try it?

```
if($(".b:has('.active')") { $('.a').addClass('disabled'); }
```