# How to get the last table row no matter the sort?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `table-responsive` class applied to a `table` and I am using a dropdown. Because of that, the dropdown always go behind the table. As I heard before, there is no solution to this situation.
So I am trying to get the last row from the table and add the `dropup` class, but as the table is sortable the last row could change in every sort.

I tried to apply this:

```
$("table#MyTable>tbody>tr:last>td>div").addClass("dropup");
```

...Worked, but as the user sort the table, the last row could not be the last row anymore.

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bqg0cyyL/** (with the last row with `dropup` applied)

How can only the last row gets the `dropup` class (no matter the sort)?

Comment: Have you tried using jQuery to identify when the sort occurs and after it does, applying the `.dropup` class to the current last row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Final Answer (success!)**

Finally thanks to this SO question: [How to run a function after an external JS script finishes running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34207170/how-to-run-a-function-after-an-external-js-script-finishes-running?noredirect=1#comment56159664_34207170) I have arrived to the solution below:

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AGE/utpq2zm1/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#MyTable").on('sorted', function(){
    var lastRow = $("#MyTable").find("tbody tr:last");
      // Removing dropup class from the row which owned it
      $("#MyTable").find("tbody tr.dropup").removeClass("dropup");
      // Adding dropup class to the current last row
      lastRow.addClass("dropup");
  });
});
```

**Below is now obsolete, but it shows the history of the final answer**

1. Use JavaScript or JQuery to identify when a sort occurs (click ocurring on the table column title).
2. If a sort occurred and the last row has the `dropup` class, then we don't need to do anything.
3. Otherwise,

   a) Remove the `dropup` class from the row which currently has it.

   b) Add the `dropup` CSS class to the row which is currently the last on the table.

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("th").click(function() {
    var lastRow = $(this).closest("table").find("tbody tr:last");
    if(!lastRow.hasClass("dropup")){
        // Removing dropup class from the row which owned it
        $(this).closest("table").find("tbody tr.dropup").removeClass("dropup");
        // Adding dropup class to the current last row
        lastRow.addClass("dropup");
    }
  });
});
```

Note that your `dropup` class is not specified in your jsfiddle, so I can only assume what you have provided. Let me know if you have any questions.

**EDIT**

The above code will not work. That is because bootstrap-sortable.js is in charge of the sorting of the table. Meaning, if a click event handler like the one above is in place, bootstrap-sortable.js will run after this is complete.

You have two options:

1. Modify your local bootstrap-sortable.js by adding a new function in the code to add the `dropup` class, like I did in my snippet above. I would first try to do call it at the end of the `function doSort($this, $table){...}` or wherever else you see appropriate.
2. You could think ok, it is understandable that something needs to happen after bootstrap-sortable.js finishes running. Perhaps looking for the change of class in the `th` then running the snippet I wrote above. Perhaps listening to some kind of event to change. In my personal attempts I have not been able to do such a thing (sadly). The easiest thing I thought of doing was listening to the change of class on the `th` after you click them (see for yourself on your web inspector). However **[this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017768/monitoring-dom-changes-in-jquery)**, and **[this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731807/listen-for-change-of-class-in-jquery)** lead me to believe this approach is either too cumbersome or simply not possible.

So give option 1 a try and see how it goes for you, otherwise it would be worth while to ask a new question with regards to how to implement an event listener after an external JS file has ended.

Comment: Thanks for your time. This is the behavior I am looking for. But in the test it does not work, see: http://jsfiddle.net/bqg0cyyL/3/. If I click in the `th` the `dropup` aren't been added to the last item. Can you please give me some more orientation? Thanks.

Comment: @Khrys please read my updated answer and let me know your thoughts

Comment: @Khrys I have posted a question, feel free to follow it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34207170/how-to-run-a-function-after-an-external-js-script-finishes-running

Comment: Amazing feedback, bro! Gonna give this a try! Thanks a bunch for not let this die.

Comment: @Khrys If this leads you to your solution then please share it and accept my answer, otherwise let's see what luck we can get on the other question. FYI when a question does go dead, you can always ask a new one by breaking it down like I just did for you, or put a bounty on it.

Comment: @Khrys if you follow the other question and find an answer on your own, answer the other question right away. Then we can link that question as the answer to this question.

Comment: @Khrys found the answer to the question, very glad to have spent time working on it, I learned something new

Comment: This was a great experience. Can't express how I am happy for the solution and to see your engagement on it. You did beyond great, AGE!

Comment: @Khrys In review of the fiddle you MIGHT want to apply this to both the LAST row and it's prior one (next to last) using `lastRow.prev().addBack().addClass("dropup");` as the second one gets covered up by the table bottom as well.

Answer (score 1):

As your primary problem is that the dropdown going behind the table. To solve that use the below jQuery code.

```
$('.table-responsive').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
     $('.table-responsive').css( "overflow", "inherit" );
});

$('.table-responsive').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
     $('.table-responsive').css( "overflow", "auto" );
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bqg0cyyL/2/

[Bootstrap button drop-down inside responsive table not visible because of scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26018756/bootstrap-button-drop-down-inside-responsive-table-not-visible-because-of-scroll)

Comment: Thanks for your time. I tried this, but the behavior of the table is weird. It triggers every dropdown, The case should trigger just the last, no matter the sort.